# The solution set of equation $\sin^{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\;+\cos^{-1}x=\cot^{-1}{\dfrac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}}-\sin^{-1}x$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

> Find the solution set of equation $\sin^{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\;+\cos^{-1}x=\cot^{-1}{\dfrac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}}-\sin^{-1}x$

**My Approach:**

$\sin^{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\;+\cos^{-1}x \; +\sin^{-1}x=\cot^{-1}{\dfrac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}}$

$\implies$$\sin^{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\;+ \frac{\pi}{2}=\cot^{-1}{\dfrac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}}$

$\implies$$\sin^{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\;+ \frac{\pi}{2}-\cot^{-1}{\dfrac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}}=0$

$\implies$$\sin^{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\;+\tan^{-1}{\dfrac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}}=0$

$\implies$$2\sin^{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=0$

I am obtaining two values of $x$ and those value are $x=1,{-1}.$

But given answer is $(-1,0)\cup \{1\}$.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The part where you went wrong is:

> $\implies$$\sin^{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\;+\tan^{-1}{\dfrac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}}=0$
> $\implies$$2\sin^{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=0$

Because, $\sin^{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=$$\tan^{-1}{\dfrac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{|x|}}$
.